# Getting error while installing android studio 4.0

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 30.0.2)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r30.0.2-windows.zip
com.intellij.util.io.HttpRequests$HttpStatusException: Request failed with status code 416
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Platform-Tools: Request failed with status code 416.
"Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 30.0.2)" failed.
Preparing "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-windows_v7_5_6.zip
Warning: This download could not be finalized from the interim state. Retrying without caching.
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-windows_v7_5_6.zip
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\A12345\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\.temp\PackageOperation02\haxm-windows_v7_5_6.zip: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer): C:\Users\A12345\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\.temp\PackageOperation02\haxm-windows_v7_5_6.zip: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
.
"Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.5.6)" failed.
Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 30.0.12)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-6466327.zip
Warning: This download could not be finalized from the interim state. Retrying without caching.
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows-6466327.zip
```

I removed my old android studio version from control panel and deleted the folder from `C:\Program Files\Android Studio`. I also tried installing by running as administrator. Any idea?

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?